# Как задать диапазон страниц в Страничном режиме Excel с помощью VBA

Tags: excel, vba

В Excel есть такая возможность как установка области печати.

```
printAreas = "$B1:$BQ49"
With PrintSheet.PageSetup
  .FitToPagesTall = 1 
  .printArea = printAreas 
 End With
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда я задаю одну страницу, то все нормально, но если я хочу задать допустим две страницы

```
printAreas = "$B1:$BQ49,$B50:$BQ98"
With PrintSheet.PageSetup
  .FitToPagesTall = 2 
  .printArea = printAreas 
 End With
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу модифицировать скрипт, чтобы увеличивать printAreas через цикл и передавать в PageSetup, но он даже два листа некорректно выводит. Объясните, пожалуйста, куда копать и есть ли решение?

Comment: Что за PageStup? PageSetup, что ли? И я не понял что-то, что у вас не получается? Что Excel делает неправильно?

Comment: На рисунке 1 диапазон один $B1:$BQ49
На втором рисунке диапазонов два "$B1:$BQ49,$B50:$BQ98"
Вопрос. Почему на втором рисунке первую страницу указал как $B1:$BQ52, хотя должен был $B1:$BQ49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ручную установку линий разбиения страниц.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.pagebreak

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(49).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

Comment: Это помогло мне, спасибо!